# TabHost and AsyncTasks in Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-tabhost, tabactivity

My app launches with a TabActivity that has four tabs, each with an associated ListView activity as its content. Ideally, I would like to launch an AsyncTask in onCreate that initializes a Drupal XMLRPC connection, and after it is finished, I create the tabHost and add the tabs in the onPostExecute. This works fine in Android 2.2 and higher, but will cause an immediate force close in 2.2 and lower. From what I've read, it seems that in Android 2.2 lower, TabActivity requires that the tabs be created before anything else is done, including AsyncTasks? If anyone has any suggestions on how to implement a TabActivity that runs an AsyncTask before starting the activity in setCurrentTab, I would be most grateful. This is the onCreate I'm using that initializes the tabHost for reference:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    tabHost = getTabHost(); //The activity TabHost
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; //Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; //Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BlogList.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Blog Posts").setIndicator("Blog Posts")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DiariesList.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Diaries").setIndicator("Diaries")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BoardList.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MGoBoard").setIndicator("MGoBoard")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, UserActivityList.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("My Account").setIndicator("My Account")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 50;
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 50;
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 50;
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 50;
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between 2.1 and 2.2 with TabHost. Sorry I can't give a full answer now as I don't have time. If you don't get an answer, make a comment with @MisterSquonk at the start and I'll look up how I solved this problem.

Comment: @MisterSquonk I don't have an answer yet and would love to know how you did it

Comment: I looked back at the code where I had the problem. Not sure if it will help but in the end I solved it in two parts. First, I created a class which extends Application and put some of my initialisation code in there. Second, my AsyncTask is a file downloader and I created a separate Activity with a 'splash screen' kind of look to it and made that my MAIN activity in the manifest. When it finishes what it's doing, it starts my TabActivity and calls finish() on itself.

Comment: @MisterSquonk the splash screen workaround is what I ended up going with. My only problem with it is if the user leaves the app on a different activity, and then resumes the app from that activity. The splash screen isn't reached, so the initial asynctask I need isn't run. I'm debating calling finish() in onPause so the user is forced back to the splash screen.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to modify the classes used for the tab content so they don't rely on the connection and create their own default 'not connected' view instead. They could then initiate the AsyncTask to make the connection and then update their content.